# Active Record: Use hash conditions in on clause

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Trying to figure out how to make a query through Active Record and still keep my dignity. The end result in sql should look like:

```
... left join works on clients.id = works.client_id and works.performed_on >= '2012-01-21' and works.performed_on <= '2012-01-28'...
```

If the date range were in the *WHERE* clause I could use hash conditions like so:

```
where(:performed_on => (date1..date2))
```

But, I need the range in the *ON* clause. Any better ideas than painfully writing the full thing out?

In my mind, something like the following would be perfect:

```
Client.joins('left join works').on('clients.id' => 'works.client_id', 'works.performed_on' => (date1..date2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could filter the result in the `WHERE` clause instead of an `ON` clause.

```
Client.joins(:works).where(:works => {:performed_on => (date1..date2)})
```

If you must filter the result in a `ON` clause then, first construct the JOIN sql:

```
join_sql = Client.send(:sanitize_sql_for_conditions, [
   "LEFT JOIN works ON clients.id = works.client_id AND (
      works.performed_on >= ? AND works.performed_on <= ? )", 
   date1, date2])

Client.joins(join_sql)
```

Comment: I can't do it in the where clause because I need all the clients included. I was hoping to avoid writing the whole thing out, I guess just because active record usually has a cleaner solution.

Comment: You can still use `sanitize_sql_for_conditions` to escape the bind variables.